# public static variable is accessible in second activity in android?

Tags: android

I am working in android. I have two acitivities in my project. I have declared a public static variable in one activity like this:-

```
public static String name="KUNTAL";
```

In my second activity i am trying to use this variable, then it is generating error that this name variable is not exist.

Is this possible to use a variable anywhere in my project if it is declared as public ?

Please suggest me what mistake i have done.?

Thank you in advance...

Comment: The info you gave us is limited. Still, check out if you reference the class file correctly

Comment: @AnirbanBhui What's the issue for you? Doesn't the accepted answer work for you?

Comment: i too wanted that
i found soltion in this topic
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11150701/which-is-best-way-to-define-constants-in-android-either-static-class-interface

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
public class Activity1 extends Activity {

    public static String name="KUNTAL";  //declare static variable. 

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    }
}

public class Activity2 extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         Activity1.name; //way to access static variable using dot operator.
    }
}
```

Comment: is there any performance problem (with activities) for doing this?

Comment: i don't think there will be a problem. but it's a good idea to use intents for passing parameters between activities, rather than static variables.

Comment: @CQM: If the static variable is also `final` (does/can never change), there will be definately no performance problem, since the compiler already inserts the *value* instead of a reference to the variable. If it is only `static` and not `final`, it still would not be a problem for performance though, since it will be treated similar to a "global variable"  from other languages.

Comment: If you understand how static declarations work then you will understand how bad this practice is  given that we have intents to pass values from one activity to another.

Answer (score 7):

I think you must access them in a 'static way', i.e.:

```
String myVar= name; // wrong
String myVar= TheClassThatContainsName.name; // right
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the variable specified as public static in any Activity but you need to access that variable by using the Activity name where you Declared it.

For Accessing in Second Activity just use ;

```
Activity1.name ="Me";
```

means that name variable belongs to Activity1 and you are using in Acvity2

Answer (score 1):

Declaring variables `public static` is not the recommended way of passing values between two activities. Use `Intent` object instead:

```
public class Activity1 extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   yourButton.setOnClicklistener(listener);
  }
}
```

//On click of some button start Activity2:

```
View.onClicklistener listener = new View.OnClickListener(){

   @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

      Intent mIntent = new Intent(Activity1.this,Activity2.class);
      mIntent.putExtra("yourKey","yourValue");
      startActivity(mIntent);

     }

};
```

//and then in your activity2 get the value:

```
public class Activity2 extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

   String yourValue = getIntent().getExtras().getString("yourKey");

  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you're using the same variable in more than one activity then make a class something like ActivityConsts{}, and declare and initialize this variable in there(in ActivityConsts). And access this variable from anywhere with the class name.
ex-

```
declare a class-
public class ActivityConsts {
//your String var
public static String name="KUNTAL";
}
```

now in your activity:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  String yourStringVar = ActivityConsts.name;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no datatype specified for your variable. Use

```
public static String name="KUNTAL";
```

Comment: sorry blessenm i typed wrongly here... yeah i typed datatype...please tell me some other cause.

Comment: Laurent and venky you both are right sir i have done mistake in accessing... thank you so much all..