# How to define constant in Android.mk

Tags: c++, android.mk

How do I define a constant to be used in .cpp file in Android.mk? The value of the constant depends on what product is being built.

Comment: Not exactly the same question, but the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11150701/which-is-best-way-to-define-constants-in-android-either-static-class-interface) may prove helpful

Comment: Looking for something like defining LOCAL_CFLAG and then #define in file, but moving #define part into makefile.